# How to start second for loop where the first for loop ends due to if condition?

Tags: django, django-templates

I am trying to start second for loop where first for loop is ended. In for loop I am using cell, in both for loop. In the first for loop I am using if condition. When condition false, we came out from the first for loop, and go in the second for loop, and **start cell from where cell in the first loop is ended..**. How we do that..

I java code we do like following, how do the same thing in Django template.

**Java Code**

```
int i=0;
   for(;i< arr.length; i++){
        if(i<5 && i<arr.length)
           break;
   }
   for(i<arr.length;i++){

   }
```

**Django Template**

```
<tr{{ row.attr_string|safe }}>
    {% spaceless %}

        {% for cell in row %}

           {% if forloop.counter < 4 %}                 
                {%  include "horizon/common/_data_grid_cell.html" %} 
               break
            {% endif %}

        {% endfor %}
        <a href="#" id="example-show" class="showLink" onclick="showHide('example');return false;">See more.</a></p> 
        {% for cell in row %}
            {%  include "horizon/common/_data_grid_cell.html" %} 
        {% endfor %}
    {% endspaceless %}
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `{% if forloop.last %}` inside your for loop to check if it is last item in your list.

You cann't break `forloop` in django template.

Alternatively you can use slice.

```
{% for cell in row|slice:"4" %}
```

for your first looop.

Comment: @izwan Mumtaz, thanks for reply, I want to start second for loop where first for loop end due to some condition.

Comment: what is the condition